# Create Serial number in rdlc report, but exclude last row

Tags: c#, asp.net, rdlc

I have a report in RDLC report on ASP.Net, in which I successfully created Serial No. for each row using `<i>=RowNumber(nothing)</i>`.

But there is a grand total coming at the last row from database. Our stored procedure return total at the last and we cannot change that procedure.
Now `RowNumber()` function create serial number for last row also which is Grand total.

Is there any method to exclude last row or apply serial number over some set of rows in RDLC?.

[image]

Comment: Can you share your coding. We can help you better that way

Comment: @darcane I added my textbox expression as screenshot. Please review the link of image.